# How to create a priority queue with an initial capacity and custom comparator in lambda notation?

Tags: java

I am using Java 10 and I am trying to create a simple priority queue. The initial capacity should be 8 (for the sake of the argument) and the priority should be the value in an array `prior`. I tried to use

```
private double[] prior;
private PriorityQueue<Integer> queue;
queue = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(8, (int v, int w) -> Double.compare(prior[v], prior[w]));
```

in my code, but that does not work. I always get the error "*The constructor PriorityQueue((int v, int w) -> {}) is undefined*". What am I doing wrong? The problem seems to be related to the lambda expression, since removing it makes the error disappear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `int` and `Integer` are not—exactly—the same thing. One is a primitive data type, the other is an Object wrapper around that primitive data type, and while Java 5 introduced Autoboxing/Autounboxing to make code that interchanges between the two less painful to write, it's still incorrect to treat them like they're the same. In this case, the lambda expression is trying to match the definition of a `Comparator<int>` (which cannot exist), and the queue is expecting a `Comparator<Integer>`, which is valid and legal.

The simplest solution is to just let the lambda expression deduce the argument types:

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(8, (v, w) -> Double.compare(prior[v], prior[w]));
```

This should compile perfectly fine and do what you expect of it.